# Regular expression how?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need help on regular expression building. There is a line of Javascript:

```
 navigator.userAgent.match(/Firefox\/3./)
```

Now it matches only Firefox 3.x. What I need is an expression that will match any Firefox version from 3rd. Meaning Firefox 3, 4, 5, ect.

Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Now I thought user agent testing was frowned upon...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it properly with regex alone. But you can do it with regex + some code:

```
var m = navigator.userAgent.match(/Firefox\/(\d+)\./);
if (m && m[1] > 3) {
  // .... firefox 3 and above ...
}
```

note: As for why you can't do it properly with regex alone, consider Firefox/10.0

Comment: You can do just about _anything_ with regex alone but that doesn't make it a good idea. You usually end up with monstrosities.

Comment: @paxdiablo: Actually, you can't parse non-regular grammar with regex (though I admit, the above situation is not non-regular). However, you CAN do just about anything with Perl6's recursive regex (but we're not talking about Perl here).

Comment: I think it is the wisest solution, since I don't want to limit the check by FF9.

Comment: Actually, you can do this with regex alone but I still think the solution above is easier to understand: `/Firefox\/([3-9]|\d\d)\d*\./`

Comment: Regex would be better in this case /Firefox\/[^012]+\./i.test(navigator.userAgent)

Comment: Or more succinctly/tersely with `(3..(1.0/0.0)) === 'Firefox/3.0'.match(/(\d+)/).captures.first.to_i`

Comment: @IvanCastellanos: That would exclude Firefox 10 (and 11, and 12 and 31 and 72 etc..)

Comment: @TinMan: You need a more specific regex than that. The real useragent string is not that simple. You'll likely get "5" instead of "3" with that (one example useragent string for FF3.0 is `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; SunOS sun4u; it-IT; ) Gecko/20080000 Firefox/3.0`)

Answer (score 3):

```
navigator.userAgent.match(/Firefox\/([3-9]|\d{2,})./)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
navigator.userAgent.match(/Firefox\/([3-9]|\d\d)./)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery I recommend that you have a look at: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

Comment: _You_ may recommend that, the jQuery bods themselves don't: "We recommend against using this property; please try to use feature detection instead (see jQuery.support)". Still, it's a good pointer.

Comment: @paxdiablo yes, for feature detection it isn't recommended, but for browser detection it is ok:

_"Because $.browser uses navigator.userAgent to determine the platform, it is vulnerable to spoofing by the user or misrepresentation by the browser itself. It is always best to avoid browser-specific code entirely where possible._ **The $.support property is available for detection of support for particular features rather than relying on $.browser**"

Answer (score 0):

How about this, for example:

```
navigator.userAgent.match(/Firefox\/[3456789]./)
```

Comment: Nice, but with the speed at which Mozilla is upping its version count, that'll last about a week and a half, when v10 arrives :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(/Firefox\/([^012]|\d{2,})\./i.test(navigator.userAgent)){
    // What you want to do
}
```

Because you need to match all firefox except the versions 0, 1 and 2.

Comment: Again, that's good for the single-digit versions but it will reject Firefox 10. After Firefox 9, the first one that will work is Firefox 33. Even with Mozilla's insanely accelerated version numbers, that will take a while :-)

Comment: It will not reject 10; what do you thing the plus sign is there for?

Comment: You may want to rethink that statement, the `+` applies to the previous pattern which is `[^012]`. In other words, it will allow one of more of any character _that isn't 0, 1 or 2._ Hence 10 _will_ fail, as will 11, 12, ..., 32, 40, 41, 42, 199999 and so on. I might be wrong, it wouldn't be the first time, but I don't think so in this case.